# comparing two strings from linked list in c++

Tags: c++

so i have this assignment where i need to 
1- read from text file of 341 lines
2- list the names of 341 persons ( first 30 characters)
3- some of the names are duplicates

so what i am trying to do is to check if the name has already been included before linking it to the list while i am creating it.

After doing some tests, i realized that both the strings i am comparing print out as the first name of the list and seem to ignore the rest of the list. when I remove the call to the boolean function the list prints out just fine.

I am student and oviously beginning, so i am afraid i might be missing a few steps? Any help or guidance is apreciated!! thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cerrno>

using namespace std;

struct Pays
{
    char nom[20+1]; /* nom du pays */
    Pays *suivant; /* pointeur sur le prochain pays */
} ;

struct Emploi
{
    char nom[29+1]; /* nom de l’emploi */
    Emploi *suivant; /* pointeur sur le prochain emploi */
} ;

struct Espion
{
    std:: string nom; /* nom de l’espion(ne) */
    Pays *listePays; /* tête de liste des pays visités */
    Emploi *listeEmploi; /* tête de liste des emplois occupés */
    Espion *suivant; /* pointeur sur le prochain espion */
} ;


bool trouverNomListe(Espion* ptr, std ::string nomAChercher)// returns true if the name is already on the list
{
     if(ptr->suivant == NULL)
            return false;
            else
                if(ptr->nom.compare(nomAChercher) == 0){
                                    std:: cout<< ptr->nom << std::endl;// checking if the function is comparing the strings
                                    return true;
                                    }
                                  else
                                      trouverNomListe(ptr->suivant, nomAChercher); //keeps looking thru the list




}


int main()
{
    const int MAX_NOM = 30, MAX_PAYS = 20, MAX_EMPLOI = 29;
    char nomFichier[50] = "espion.txt";
    int n = 0;

    std:: string infoEspion;


    Espion *actu = NULL;
    Espion *debut = NULL;
    Espion *fin = NULL;
    Espion *nouveau = NULL;

    std :: ifstream aLire;
    aLire.open(nomFichier, std::ios::in);

    if(!aLire.is_open()){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }





    while(std::getline(aLire, infoEspion))
    {
                if(debut == NULL){// if the list is empty
                      nouveau = new Espion;
                      nouveau -> nom = infoEspion.substr(0,30);
                      nouveau -> suivant = NULL;
                      debut = nouveau;
                      actu = nouveau;
                      fin = nouveau;
                      std::cout << actu -> nom<< std::endl;  
                      }
                      else
                      if(trouverNomListe(debut, infoEspion.substr(0,30)) == false )
                      {

                          nouveau = new Espion;
                          nouveau -> nom = infoEspion.substr(0,30);
                          nouveau -> suivant = NULL;
                          actu -> suivant = nouveau;
                          fin = nouveau;
                          actu = nouveau;
                          std::cout << actu -> nom<< std::endl;  
                          }





    }




    aLire.close();


    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: mixing char arrays with std::strings, why?

Comment: it was not my intention, that was given by the teacher. But from what i have been looking into it seems that i should be using strings.. which is what im trying to learn to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `trouverNomListe` function is recursive, which is incorrect. It should simply go through the list sequentially, e.g.

```
bool trouverNomListe(Espion* ptr, std ::string nomAChercher)// returns true if the name is already on the list
{
    while (ptr)
    {
         if(ptr->nom.compare(nomAChercher) == 0)
              return true;
         ptr = ptr->suivant;
    }
    return false;
}
```

There are several other problems with your code too but this seems to be the main issue.